# How to determine if I'm uploading something by downloading a torrent?

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, upload, p2p

First of all I'm not exactly leeching (my share ratio is near 1.0 and don't want to stop uploading and continue downloading but stop both).

Secondly, yesterday there was an announcement that we should not use bitTorrents because the whole dorm will be cut-off Internet and particular users will be punished by faculty.

Now, I'm confused if I'm uploading something or not. How does it work? I use Free download manager (FDM) because I'm not usually downloading torrents. I downloaded just few things using P2P. I also start FDM only when I want to download something bigger.

I know just that I'm uploading when downloading, but after the download is finished, am I uploading something as seed?

If FDM is not running it shouldn't upload anything, am I right? Also when I delete those few files that I downloaded through a torrent, I should be sure that I'm not uploading, right?

How to make sure I'm not uploading anything?

Answer (score 1):

If FDM is not running it can't obviously upload or download anything (make sure it's really not running and not just minimized). When it's running, even if you have completed a download you will still upload, you will be a seeder. I don't think there's a way to stop uploading other than closing the software or deleting the file (note that deleting the files might cause them to be downloaded again and so the upload will continue, I don't know that specific software wery well). If you can't afford to upload even a small piece of data you better stop using torrents, there is no way to completely avoid uploading.